# Currying syntax in scala

Tags: scala, currying

The syntax of currying in scala is for example

`def f(x: Int, b: Int) = x + y`

is

`def f(x: Int)(b: Int) = x + y`

And currying for sum to sum for given range a and b is

```
  def sum(f: Int => Int, a: Int, b: Int) = {
    ...
  }

  sum(x=>x, 3, 6)          // outcome is 18 (3+4+5+6)
```

is

```
  def sum(f: Int => Int): (Int, Int) => Int = {
        def sumF(a: Int, b: Int): Int =
          if (a > b) 0
          else f(a) + sumF(a + 1, b)
        sumF
  }

  sum(x=>x)(3, 6)          // outcome is 18 (3+4+5+6)
```

But I don't understand why colon(:) 
exists between (f: Int => Int) and (Int, Int)

in `def sum(f: Int => Int): (Int, Int) => Int = {`

instead of

`def sum(f: Int => Int)(Int, Int) => Int = {`

Answer (score 2):

Your `sum` example is *not* curried.  If you wanted it curried you'd do something like:

```
def sum(f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int): Int =
    if (a > b) 0
    else f(a) + sum(f)(a + 1, b)

sum(x=>x)(3, 6)  // res0: Int = 18
```

Your code defines a method that takes a single argument, `def sum(f: Int => Int)`. That argument is a function that takes and `Int` and returns an `Int`. So no currying involved.

This `sum` method returns a function, `: (Int, Int) => Int`. This returned function takes 2 `Int`s and returns and `Int`. Invoking this `sum` method looks like currying, but it's not.

```
sum(x=>x)(3, 6)
```

Instead you are invoking `sum()` with a single argument (`x=>x`) and then invoking the returned function with two arguments (`3,6`).

Comment: Isn't this still currying?  It's just explicitly returning the curried function rather than using Scala's special syntax.

Comment: @puhlen, I see your point. A curried method takes an arg and returns a function, so what's the difference? I would argue that the 2nd `sum` definition doesn't use Scala currying _syntax_ so, even though it accomplishes the same thing, I'm not sure it can be _called_ an example of Scala currying.

Answer (score 1):

`(Int, Int) => Int` between `:` and `=` specify the function's return type, i.e, it says `sum` will return another method of signature `(Int, Int) => Int` which takes two `Int` and returns another `Int`, and this is the signature of your inner `sumF` function:

You can rewrite this to the currying syntax as follows:

```
def sum(f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
    def sumF(a: Int, b: Int): Int =
        if (a > b) 0
        else f(a) + sumF(a + 1, b)

    sumF(a, b)
}
```

This will more or less do the same thing as the method defined in OP:

```
sum(x => x)(3, 6)
// res11: Int = 18
```

But these two definitions are not exactly the same, for instance, for the currying syntax defined here, if you want to generate a new method from it, you have to specify the variable type, like:

```
val mysum: (Int, Int)=> Int = sum(x => x)
```

But for the one in OP, it can be simply `val mysum = sum(x => x)` as the return type of `sum` as already been specified.